# Change git user and key from Bamboo Agent

Tags: git, authentication, continuous-integration, bamboo

I have a requirement to push to a stash repository from Bamboo.

The default bamboo agents have restricted read access, but I need a specific plan which is able to push code to a repository.

(My Stash repo only accepts keys.)

Unfortunately I can't create a new agent with a different ssh key.

Is there a way to create a user mid plan, then delete the user after the plan is completed?

Or a better way to handle this?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Are you using bamboo linked repositories? If so are you using the Stash repository host/type? Are you using the Git repository host/type? Are you manually doing the checkout in a task in your plan and actually putting keys on the agents directly?

Comment: No, I have the git repository host/type, and I have tried using both checkout methods!

Comment: If you want to duplicate the repository in bamboo then you should be able to create a repo with a key that can push what you want and use that only from that plan I think. Unfortunately you can't, with stash by default, limit that key to *only* being able to modify the branch/etc. that you want.